# Make simple multiline Glossary

Tags: tables, glossaries

I would like to make a simple glossary that looks sort of like this:

[image]

That allows me to make tabs that stay tabs even if the break a line. so that it looks like an invisible table, yet still does regular line breaks.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `description` environment is made for that. The lengths used in the environment, such as the label's width, can be changed easily using the `enumitem` package (see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for details).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{
    labelwidth=22mm, 
    labelsep=0mm, 
    leftmargin=22mm
}
\begin{document}
\section*{Glossary}
\begin{description}
    \item[Dog] An animal that makes dog noises. Some more text to see if the line will break as it should. 
    \item[Cat] An animal that makes cat noises
    \item[Mouse] An animal that makes neither dog nor cat noises
    \item[Key] Not even an animal
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tabto,enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\mytab}[1]{\tabto{4.5cm}\parbox[t]{%
        \dimexpr\textwidth-4.5cm-\labelwidth-\labelsep}{#1}}
\begin{document}
    Glossary
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] Dog \mytab{An \texttt{animal} that makes dog noises and irritates me no end }
        \item[] Cat \mytab{An \texttt{animal} that makes cat noises }

    \end{itemize}
    
    
\end{document}
```